# Do robotics applications run in an operating system or are they written entirely as operating system?

Tags: robotics

Do robotics applications run in an operating system, such as those used in industrial automation, computer vision, or are they developed entirely as operating systems? I'm curious about the role of operating systems in the field of robotics.

Comment: It is done both ways depending on resources. However, it makes little difference as long as it is done right to get desired results. An operating system is just another program, albeit a program that manages other programs, allowing them to run on its behalf. There are annoyances with determinism when multiple "programs" are competing for use of resources, so people made operating systems that specifically manage that too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. There are many kinds of robots. They run on many different kinds of systems. There might be a operating system in any of the building blocks the robot uses or there might not.

The thing is control systems (robots are control systems) have often real fixed timing requirements. So having a external system manage timing might be problematic. Normal operating systems dont guarantee real time access so you usually need a heavily modified or specifically made real time operating system.

But there are other ways to do this too. See the reason you need a os is to share resources on one system, but you might have multiple semi independent systems etc etc.

And then there is the question of where the robotic system ends. Oftentimes there is still a computer somewhere that can talk to the robot. So if i connect my laptop to the robot controller to give it commands is my laptops os now a robotic os?